# JavaScript - Why can't I call a variable "name"?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Why can't you call a variable in JS "name"?

```
var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
var name = document.createElement("div");

wrapper.appendChild(name); // TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
```

When I type "name" in the console in a new tab it returns an empty string?

I use Chrome.

Comment: You should be able to call a variable `name`. Calling `name` in the console is the same as accessing the `name` property of `window`.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome.  What browser are you using?

Comment: [MDN window name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name)

Comment: Don't create so many globals and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `window.name` is a magic property of `window` object and can hold only strings (any object, including arrays, is coerced to primitive type and becomes something like `"[Object Object]"`). Variables defined in global scope become properties of global object and it can cause conflicts.

You can have variable `name` in any nonglobal scope. Simple workaround can be to wrap your code in immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE).

```
(function(){

    var wrapper = document.createElement("div");

    var name = document.createElement("div");


    wrapper.appendChild(name); // workd


    document.body.appendChild(wrapper);

}());
```

Comment: This is correct answer. I would also add that setting `window.name` automatically preforms casting to String type, so setting `window.name` will result in something like `window.name = [object HTMLDivElement]`.

Comment: I have added this information. TIL: `window.name` can hold **only** strings, not other primitive types.

Answer (score 3):

'name' is a predefined name of implementation-dependent JavaScript objects, methods, or properties, you should avoid to use this as a name for a variable, though it's not a reserved word and might work in some browsers