# Getting error while printing through array in Java script

Tags: javascript

I am using split function to remove the comma from an array which is displayed while using for loop to print an array but when i am using this code

```
 <script>
   var name = ["A", "B", "C"];
   var name_split = name.split(',')
   for(var i=0;i<name_split.length;i++)
   {
      document.write("\n",name_split[i],"\n");
   }
  </script>
```

I get the O/P for the above code as expected : A B C. But when i use the same code with different variables and some more methods it gives error,for instance this code

```
 <script>
   var intro = ["Hello","World","etc"];
   var intro_split = intro.split(',');
   for(var a=0;a<intro_split.length;a++)
     {
         document.write("\n",intro_split[a],"\n");
     }
 </script>
```

The error for this code is : TypeError: intro.split is not a function. Why is it happening ?

Comment: I think 'split' function used for string not an array!

Comment: You get the error because there is no Array.split. you already have an array there, no need to make a new array

Comment: The reason the first one works is the use of the variable "name" in the global scope.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27446366/javascript-why-cant-i-call-a-variable-name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'split' function is used for string, like this code:

```
var intro = "Hello,World,etc";
var intro_split = intro.split(',');
for(var i=0;i<intro_split.length;i++)
  {
     document.write("\n",intro_split[i],"\n");
  }
```

for printing array items use this code:

```
<script>
  var intro = ["Hello","World","etc"];
  for(var a=0;a<intro.length;a++)
  {
     document.write("\n",intro[a],"\n");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: so what to do in array to get rid of comma's while printing it can u snip a code for it thnx in advance

Answer (score 1):

The reason your first snipped worked is because `name` is a name of JavaScript built-in properties/methods: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

As linked in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38161609/getting-error-while-printing-through-array-in-java-script#comment63751623_38161609), "name"...

> ...can hold only strings and any object, including arrays, is coerced to primitive type.

So, it will coerce your array to a string (where you can use `split`). For instance:

```
var name = ["A", "B", "C"];
console.log(name);//returns "A, B, C"
```

But:

```
var test = ["A", "B", "C"];
console.log(test);//returns ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You really do not need to call `split(character-to-split-by)` - you already have an array of strings (which `split`, called on a string, would give you an array of string/characters). So in this case, simply loop through `intro` array:

```
<script>
   var intro = ["Hello","World","etc"];   
   for(var a=0;a<intro.length;a++)
     {
         document.write("\n",intro[a],"\n");
     }
 </script>
```

Alternatively, if you really want to try out the use of split, then you can `join` the array first (by default the joining is done by comma `,`). In that case, you could do something like  this:

```
  <script>
       var intro = ["Hello","World","etc"];  
       var veryUnnecessaryStuff = intro.join();
       var intro_split = veryUnnecessaryStuff.split(','); 
       for(var a=0;a<intro_split;a++)
         {
             document.write("\n",intro_split[a],"\n");
         }
  </script>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: yeah thanks for explaining  both the content clearly